# Evaluating the unique limit

Tags: calculus, limits

How to evaluate this limit?

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{(1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^{2n})}{((1-x)(1-x^2)\cdots(1-x^n))^2}$$

I tried l'Hospital's rule but couldn't proceed further.

Comment: I edited the body of your post; please ensure it remains as you intended.

Comment: @Clayton Yes it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
L
&=
\lim_{x\to1}
\frac{(1-x)(1-x^2)\dots(1-x^{2n})}{((1-x)(1-x^2)\dots(1-x^n))^2}
\\
&=
\lim_{x\to1}
\frac{(1-x^{n+1})(1-x^{n+2})\dots(1-x^{2n})}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\dots(1-x^n)}
\\
&=
\lim_{x\to1}
\prod_{1\le k\le n}\frac{1-x^{n+k}}{1-x^k}
\\
&=
\prod_{1\le k\le n}\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1-x^{n+k}}{1-x^k}
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\textrm{now use l'Hospital or factorize $(1-x)$}
\\
&=
\prod_{1\le k\le n}\frac{n+k}{k}
\\
&=
\frac{(n+1)(n+2)\dots(2n)}{1\cdot 2\dots n}
\\
&=
\frac{(2n)!}{n!\cdot n!}
\\
&=\binom {2n}n\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Example using a computer algebra program in a special case, $n=10$:

```
var('k,x');
n = 10;
limit( prod( [ 1-x^k for k in [1..2*n] ] ) / prod( [1-x^k for k in [1..n] ] )^2, x=1 )
```

This produces...

```
sage: limit( prod( [ 1-x^k for k in [1..2*n] ] ) / prod( [1-x^k for k in [1..n] ] )^2, x=1 )
184756
sage: binomial(2*n,n)
184756
```

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You can cancel out factors in the denominator with factors in the numerator, leaving $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{(1-x^{n+1})\cdots(1-x^{2n})}{(1-x)\cdots(1-x^n)}.$$

Now you can use the fact that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=(\lim_{x\to a}f(x))(\lim_{x\to a}g(x))$ assuming both limits on the right exist. This allows you to split up the inside part of the limit into 'easy' quotients that you can apply l'Hospital's rule to.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\frac{(1-x)(1-x^2)....(1-x^{2n})}{((1-x)(1-x^2)...(1-x^n))^2}\\
=\frac{(1-x)^{2n}}{(1-x)^{2n}}\frac{1\cdot (1+x)....(1+x+...+x^{2n-1})}{(1\cdot (1+x)...(1+x+...+x^{n-1}))^2}\to \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

One possible way:

Use $$1-x^{k+1}=(1-x)\sum_{i=0}^kx^i$$ to get rid of factor of $(1-x)$